# How can i post my website content to wordpress and blogger sites

Tags: wordpress, blogger, socialshare

How do i share my website content to wordpress blog and google's blogger like facebook share, twitter share, without any third party tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1:

Go to your theme’s `function.php` file and paste below code. This will add sharing button at the `bottom of the post`

```
function crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
    if(is_singular() || is_home()){

        // Get current page URL 
        $crunchifyURL = get_permalink();

        // Get current page title
        $crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());

        // Get Post Thumbnail for pinterest
        $crunchifyThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

        // Construct sharing URL without using any script
        $twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$crunchifyTitle.'&amp;url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;via=Crunchify';
        $facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$crunchifyURL;
        $googleURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$crunchifyURL;
        $bufferURL = 'https://bufferapp.com/add?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;text='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Based on popular demand added Pinterest too
        $pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;media='.$crunchifyThumbnail[0].'&amp;description='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Add sharing button at the end of page/page content
        $content .= '<div class="crunchify-social">';
        $content .= '<h5>SHARE ON</h5> <a class="crunchify-link crunchify-twitter" href="'. $twitterURL .'" target="_blank">Twitter</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank">Facebook</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-googleplus" href="'.$googleURL.'" target="_blank">Google+</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-buffer" href="'.$bufferURL.'" target="_blank">Buffer</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-pinterest" href="'.$pinterestURL.'" target="_blank">Pin It</a>';
        $content .= '</div>';

        return $content;
    }else{
        // if not a post/page then don't include sharing button
        return $content;
    }
};
add_filter( 'the_content', 'crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');
```

- Step 2:

Open `style.css` file of your WordPress theme and put below code for better styling.

```
    .crunchify-link {
    padding: 4px 8px 6px 8px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.crunchify-link:hover,.crunchify-link:active {
    color: white;
}

.crunchify-twitter {
    background: #00aced;
}

.crunchify-twitter:hover,.crunchify-twitter:active {
    background: #0084b4;
}

.crunchify-facebook {
    background: #3B5997;
}

.crunchify-facebook:hover,.crunchify-facebook:active {
    background: #2d4372;
}

.crunchify-googleplus {
    background: #D64937;
}

.crunchify-googleplus:hover,.crunchify-googleplus:active {
    background: #b53525;
}

.crunchify-buffer {
    background: #444;
}

.crunchify-buffer:hover,.crunchify-buffer:active {
    background: #222;
}

.crunchify-pinterest {
    background: #bd081c;
}

.crunchify-pinterest:hover,.crunchify-pinterest:active {
    background: #bd081c;
}
.crunchify-social {
    margin: 20px 0px 25px 0px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

- If you want to show Sharing button at the top of the post then use this code:

```php
function crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
    if(is_singular() || is_home()){

        // Get current page URL 
        $crunchifyURL = get_permalink();

        // Get current page title
        $crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());

        // Get Post Thumbnail for pinterest
        $crunchifyThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

        // Construct sharing URL without using any script
        $twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$crunchifyTitle.'&amp;url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;via=Crunchify';
        $facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$crunchifyURL;
        $googleURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$crunchifyURL;
        $bufferURL = 'https://bufferapp.com/add?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;text='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Based on popular demand added Pinterest too
        $pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;media='.$crunchifyThumbnail[0].'&amp;description='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Add sharing button at the end of page/page content
        $variable .= '<div class="crunchify-social">';
        $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-twitter" href="'. $twitterURL .'" target="_blank">Twitter</a>';
        $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank">Facebook</a>';
        $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-googleplus" href="'.$googleURL.'" target="_blank">Google+</a>';
        $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-buffer" href="'.$bufferURL.'" target="_blank">Buffer</a>';
        $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-pinterest" href="'.$pinterestURL.'" target="_blank">Pin It</a>';
        $variable .= '</div>';

        return $variable.$content;
    }else{
        // if not a post/page then don't include sharing button
        return $variable.$content;
    }
};
add_filter( 'the_content', 'crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');
```

Take a look [here](http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-social-sharing-button-without-any-plugin-and-script-loading-wordpress-speed-optimization-goal/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i want to share my website content to wordpress blog and blogspot.